# Count of distinct values per day, excluding reoccuring until value changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, distinct

I'm really struggling with how to explain this so I'll try and give you the format of the table below, and the desired outcome.

I have a table which contains a uniqueID, date, userID and result. I'm trying to count the number of results that are 'Correct' per day, but I only want to count unique occurances based on the userID column. I then want to exclude any furhter occurances of 'Correct' for that particular userID, until the result for the userID changes to 'Success'.

```
UID Date        UserID Result
1   01/01/2014  5    Correct
2   01/01/2014  5    Correct
3   02/01/2014  4    Correct
4   03/01/2014  4    Correct
5   03/01/2014  5    Incorrect
6   03/01/2014  4    Incorrect
7   05/01/2014  5    Correct
8   07/01/2014  4    Correct
9   08/01/2014  5    Success
10  08/01/2014  4    Success
```

Based on the above data, I'd expect to see the below:

```
Date        Correct Success
01/01/2014  1       0
02/01/2014  1       0
03/01/2014  0       0
05/01/2014  0       0
07/01/2014  0       0
08/01/2014  0       2
```

Can anyone help? I'm using SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `count(distinct)` with `case`:

```
select date,
       count(distinct case when result = 'Correct' then UserId end) as Correct,
       count(distinct case when result = 'Success' then UserId end) as Success
from data d
group by date
order by date;
```

EDIT:

The above counts `correct` on all occurrences.  If you only want the first one to be counted:

```
select date,
       count(case when result = 'Correct' and seqnum = 1 then UserId end) as Correct,
       count(case when result = 'Success' and seqnum = 1 then UserId end) as Success
from (select d.*,
             row_number() over (partition by UserId, result order by Uid) as seqnum
      from data d
     ) d;
```

In this case, the `distinct` is unnecessary.

Comment: Good Answer. @Gordon I have seen some queries like above. They have used 1 instead of column name in count like 'count(distinct case when result = 'Correct' then 1 end)'. does it make any difference?

Comment: @user2315555 . . . A good answer, but I think to the wrong question.  The edited version should be closer to what the OP wants.

Comment: @user2315555 have a look at this [Q&A](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2511) for an explanation as to why some people use 1 instead of a column name, especially if that column is nullable. Even though that post is for Oracle, it applies to SQL aswell

Comment: This doesn't work. It will count the recurring 'Correct' results when I only want to count the first one until the next result for that ID is 'Success'

Comment: @user2315555 . . . For your question about count, yes, it makes a big, big difference because this is `count(distinct)`.  For a conditional count, I use `sum()`.

Comment: @AMC . . . Look at the edited version.  That should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks both of you for explaining. For count (distinct), it will completely ruin it :)